# Problem after removing ghostscript extra packages are removed automatically and screen is black

Tags: ubuntu, installation, ghostscript, dpkg, gnome-shell

## How its happened?

Very simple by just removing the `ghostscript` package.
In the `dpkg` log it seems the following packages are removed after ghostscript uninstallation: **gnome-shell**, **gnome-settings-daemons**, **gnome-settings**, **gvfs & gvfs-daemons**, **udisks2**, **network-manager**, **policykit-1**, **libpack**.

I tried to install packages one by one and as you can see my `network-manager` is removed too, therefore I can not connect to the internet to download packages online & I should try to install packages offline. Every time I'm trying to install one package every package has plenty of required packages that I should download and install too, and as you know it's very hard and tricky.

## Question:

How can I install whole packages with their required packages once?
There is any simpler solution to install one network tool instead of `network-manager to just connect to the internet?.

## Setup

- Ubuntu version 20.4

Comment: You should ask over at https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: They're pretty slow to respond.

Comment: This isn't a Ghostscript question, in fact it isn't a programming question and is really somewhat off-topic (as implied by orhtej2) If you want to complain about the package uninstaller, then you should talk to the Ubuntu Ghostscript package maintainer.